# Java code recursive and iterative methods have different answers

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I'm starting to lose hope and sanity...
I'm learning Java code and trying to write a program for choosing hobby, but it must be done by two methods and mine give different numbers... I don't know where to look for mistake or how to make it right. Please help!

```
 public static int chooseHobbyRecursive(int[] startNumbers, int day) {
    if (day == 0){
        return startNumbers [0];
    } else if (day == 1) {
        return startNumbers [1];
    } else if (day == 2) {
        return startNumbers [2];
    } else if (day == 3) {
        return startNumbers [3];
    } else {
        int prev = chooseHobbyRecursive(startNumbers, day - 1);
        int prevPrePrev = chooseHobbyRecursive(startNumbers, day - 3);
        return (prev * prevPrePrev) % 10 + 1;
    }
    }
   

    public static int chooseHobbyIterative(int[] startNumbers, int day) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        numbers.add(startNumbers[0]);
        numbers.add(startNumbers[1]);
        numbers.add(startNumbers[2]);
        numbers.add(startNumbers[3]);

        for (int d = 0; d < day; d++) {
            int index = d + 4; 
            int prev = numbers.get(index - 1); 
            int prePrePrev = numbers.get(index - 3); 
            numbers.add((prev * prePrePrev) % 10 + 1);
        }

        return numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to rewrite the code but it usually either dies with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or have different numbers

Output:

```
=== Day 1 ===
Iterative = 4 | Recursive = 1

=== Day 2 ===
Iterative = 1 | Recursive = 20

=== Day 5 ===
Iterative = 8 | Recursive = 1

=== Day 15 ===
Iterative = 2 | Recursive = 3
```

**UPD**:
*The task states:* At the very beginning student writes two numbers: the day and month of his birth, then two numbers - two halves of the current year. For example, if he was born on January 21 and the year is 2023, the first four numbers are 21 1 20 23. Each next number is obtained by the rule: the previous day and two days before it are taken, multiplied, the remainder of the division by 10 is taken, then 1 is added, so that there is numbering from one. Each such number will be from 1 to 10 and will be the number of the hobby he will be doing that day.

I was given the iterative method and my job to create a recursive one, but I don't understand how (I figured how to make a recursive part), but somehow have no idea how to make the method chooseHobbyRecursive right.

I would appreciate the explanation or/and the parts where I'm wrong or any advice really. Thanks!

Comment: Your two implementation don't behave the same even for the simplest inputs. For example, for `day == 0`, the recursive method returns the first element of  `startNumbers` array, and the iterative method returns the last element of the `List`, which will be `startNumbers[3]` in this case. Even without knowing the desired logic, the iterative method looks wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: also note, basically related to the same problem of first comment, that `day` in second code is not the same as in first since adding `4` to it (maybe start the loop with `d = 4` and do not add `4`; or end at `day-4`)

Comment: What is the specification for a "program for choosing hobby" exactly? What's the expected output for different sample inputs? Please avoid emotional appeals like "I'm starting to lose hope and sanity" and focus on stating plainly what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.